# Tips on Identifying Geometric and $e^x$ series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am having trouble with identifying 2 types of series in *various formats* and was hoping that someone could share a few tips or tricks that has helped them in the past with the identification.  The two types of series that I am seeking assistance on are Geometric and $e^x$ series.  I understand how to put them both in the general format and find convergence or divergence.

Any advice on how to determine these two series would be helpful.

I thank you all in advance for you help and time on this.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. What is your problem? How can we help you? You identified the functions related to these Taylor expansions. The only thing you need to determine is the radius of convergence of these series.

Comment: My question as stated in the first two sentences is about tips and tricks to identifying these two types of series.  Correction was only needed if my general forms were in correct.  However, thank you for confirming my general forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1) Look at the Taylor series of $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$ (radius of convergence is $1$).

2) Determine the Taylor series of $\exp(x)$ (the radius of convergence is $\infty$), hence this series is true for all finite values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (+1) nice answer, just saying that $1/1-x$ is not only the Taylor series. In fact $1+x+x^2+...$ is a geometric sum (every element is a multiplicity by $x$ of the previous one) and $1/1-x$ is the formula for infinite geometric sums.

Comment: I agree, that this is a fine answer as far as confirming my general forms are correct, however, what I was looking for, and I do apologize if my question was not clear enough, was tips and tricks if any exist on identifying the various forms that the geometric series and $e^x$ series takes on.  Thanks